# Do I need a database configuration to use JWPL?

Tags: java, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, jwpl

I am trying to understand the [Java Wikipedia Library](https://code.google.com/p/jwpl/) API (JWPL).

To instanciate a Wikipedia object, I need a `DatabaseConfiguration`. See the code below.

```
// configure the database connection parameters
DatabaseConfiguration dbConfig = new DatabaseConfiguration();
dbConfig.setHost("SERVER_URL");
dbConfig.setDatabase("DATABASE");
dbConfig.setUser("USER");
dbConfig.setPassword("PASSWORD");
dbConfig.setLanguage(Language.german);

// Create the Wikipedia object
Wikipedia wiki = new Wikipedia(dbConfig);
```

What exactly is the `DatabaseConfiguration` and why do I need it? The Javadoc isn't clear about it.

What I need to do is to get the category of a word with the API, isn't it a way to use it like:

```
String category = wiki.getCathegory("word");
```

without database connexion?

Comment: You need to connect to the DB to obtain the category for the given word.  where do you suppose the category would come from?

Comment: What are the settings? There isn't an other way to get the data? via xml, json, ...

Comment: The JWPL does not provide you with 'live' data - it seems that "the data is shipped as SQL insert statements" for you to use in your own DB - the settings would the the details of your own dB. https://code.google.com/p/jwpl/wiki/JWPL_FAQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their [**documentation page**](https://code.google.com/p/jwpl/wiki/JWPLDocumentation) (emphasis is mine)

**JWPL is for you:**

- If you need structured access to Wikipedia in Java.

**JWPL is not for you:**

- If you need to query live data. JWPL works on an optimized database,
  i.e. you are querying **a static Wikipedia dump**. This gives much better
  performance and lightens the load on the Wikipedia servers.

So the DB settings are to be provided by you.

This means you have to install your own Database server, insert all the dumped data given by Wikipedia and query your own database.

You would have to update your Database regularly if you need 'fresh' results.

If you need up-to-date (i.e. live) results, you would have to use a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

JWPL doesn't provide you access to Wikipedia, it provides an API to the Wikipedia database. You need to download a dump of the database, as detailed [here](https://code.google.com/p/jwpl/wiki/HowToGetWikipediaDumps).

You will also need to be running some form of an SQL database that can handle a 4GB+ MyISAM tables, if you are planning on using an English dump. Details on that can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/jwpl/wiki/JWPL_MySQL4).